# Flurry Parameter limitation

Tags: flurry

In my application i have an event which has been occurred for more than 1000 times when i am trying to retrieve that event along with the parameters i am getting only 500 parameter values only.

Is there any way to get all the records?

Api call:

http://api.flurry.com/eventMetrics/EventapiAccessCode=APIACCESSCODE&apiKey=APIKEY&startDate=STARTDATE&endDate=ENDDATE&eventName=EVENTNAME&versionName=VERSIONNAME

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Event parameter show up the top 500 values. All parameter values beyond the top 500 get grouped into 'Others'.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: Thank you for ur response... Cant we get all the values?

Comment: How to retrieve "others" values? Is there any api for that?

Comment: This anwser seems to be outdated. From http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Events "Each Event can have up to 10 parameters, and each parameter can have an infinite number of values associated with it. For example, for the ‘Author’ parameter, there may be 1,000 possible authors who wrote an article. We can keep track of each author via this single parameter."

Comment: Are there also limitations about name of the event? Characters used? Max length?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to drill down to the info beyond the top 500 values.

> There is currently no way to drill down beyond the Top 500 values. If
>   you require additional information, one best practice is to create
>   groupings for the Parameter values (e.g. if the values can be
>   individual numbers, for example, create groups such as ‘1-10,’ ‘11-20’
>   and so on, rather than storing each individual value).

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/faq/events/